# Unable to open nested jar file (spring-boot-starter-web) when running from jar

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application that runs fine via IntelliJ's Spring Boot run configuration as well as with `mvn spring-boot:run`, however, when I attempt to package via `mvn package` I get the following error when running from `java -jar application.jar`

> **java.io.IOException: Unable to open nested jar file
>   'lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar'**
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:349)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:112)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:96)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:75)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:60)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
>
> Caused by: **java.io.IOException: Unable to find ZIP central directory
>   records after reading 2227 bytes**
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryEndRecord.(CentralDirectoryEndRecord.java:64)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:118)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:387)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:357)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:343)
>           ... 5 more

This *seems* similar to [java.io.IOException when running Spring Boot jar on Centos 6.4 / Open JDK 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403987/java-io-ioexception-when-running-spring-boot-jar-on-centos-6-4-open-jdk-1-7-0) but the solution was to remove a corrupt jar file related to TLD libraries and that question doesn't reference which nested jar couldn't be loaded (so I'm unsure if it's exactly the same issue). I have tried deleting and recreating the `~/.m2/repository` directory to no avail. I've also tried different versions of Spring Boot (as I've never run across this issue before) with no luck.

My pom file is below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.oranization</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!--Spring-->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring-->

        <!--Logging-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Logging-->

        <!--Database-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp-spring</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Database-->

        <!--Joda Time-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Joda Time-->

        <!--Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.14-beta</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Test-->
        <!--Web Support-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
            <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Web Support-->

        <!--Utils-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.danielbechler</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-object-diff</artifactId>
            <version>0.93.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Utils-->

        <!--Reactor-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-bus</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Reactor-->

        <!--Swagger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Swagger-->

        <!--Elasticsearch-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AWS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.33</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--PDF processing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--PDF processing-->
        <!--Doc/Docx file processing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Doc/Docx file processing-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>application</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Copy Dockerfile -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/docker</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>zip-files</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <zip destfile="${basedir}/target/app.zip"
                                     basedir="${basedir}/target"
                                     includes="Dockerfile, Dockerrun.aws.json, application.jar"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Edit**
After deleting the `~/m2/repository` directory in Finder and emptying the Trash, I did a Reimport from Intellij and then a `package` from the Maven Projects menu. When trying to run the final product with `java -jar target/application.jar` I get a new error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   java.io.IOException: Unable to read bytes
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:53)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:45)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.(JarLauncher.java:34)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to read bytes
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Bytes.get(Bytes.java:53)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntryData.(JarEntryData.java:70)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntryData.fromInputStream(JarEntryData.java:212)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.loadJarEntries(JarFile.java:155)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:122)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:104)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:95)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.(JarFileArchive.java:65)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.(JarFileArchive.java:61)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.createArchive(Launcher.java:152)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:50)
>           ... 3 more

Comment: I guess you have java jdk7 in your PATH. Check the java version `java -v` and see if it is Java 1.7 or 1.8.

Comment: It's Java 8: `java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)`

Comment: This does looks like Spring Boot jar on Centos... question. Have u tried cleaning maven local repo, rebuilding index, then cleaning project n then packaging?

Comment: @SanjayRawat I have tried removing the `~/.m2/repository` directory. Is there another step to that I should try?

Comment: I am not sure about intelliJ, but for Eclipse, you should try Rebuild Index on Local Repo of Maven. Then `mvn clean` `mvn package`.
There is one option called Reimport All maven Project in IntelliJ, try that n then of course `mvn clean` & `mvn package`.

Comment: @SanjayRawat interesting results: when I deleted the `repository` directory from Finder and then tried to empty the trash just to be sure, I got an error that the files were in use. I then closed Intellij and was able to empty the trash. Now, resolving dependencies via Intellij and doing a `package` from Intellij, I get a `Cannot read bytes` error (full error in the edit above).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107902/discussion-between-sanjay-rawat-and-chris-thompson).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616250/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-files-per-jar). Despite Java 8 supposedly supporting a huge number of files, I had about 77k in my jar file (due to the inclusion of the `node_modules` directory from my React frontend) and when I configured the exclude filters properly, it worked like a charm.

Moral of the story, hitting that maximum file limit will cause weird things to happen.

Comment: Node_Modules folders literally consists of billions of files xD. I guess that was a lesson learned.